# fadeOut/fadeIn image over element

Tags: jquery, css, image, fade

I currently have a div with a image overlaid that I am currently using the following code to fadeout the image to show the text in the element underneath:

```
$(".Content_Frame_Image").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});
```

However because im only making it invisible I cant get the links to work underneath, you can see a sample here http://playing.everythingcreative.co.uk

If I use the fadeout method then it wont fadein on hover...

Comment: You might be able to use CSS pointer-events for this.

Comment: tried that but it just ignores the fadeout element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's about:

```
$(".Content_Frame_Container")
    .each(function(){
        $(this).find('.Content_Frame_Image');
    })
    .hover( 
        function(){
            $(this).find('.Content_Frame_Image').stop().fadeOut('slow');
        }, 
        function(){
            $(this).find('.Content_Frame_Image').stop().fadeIn('slow');
        }
    );
```

tested it with chrome dev-tools -- should work nicely.

Comment: _If I use the fadeout method then it wont fadein on hover..._

Comment: sounds really strange?!?!
should work! (maybe the functions need to be swapped? *lookingUp*)

Comment: 2. if you blend it out, you can't hover it, because it's not visible :D you have to set it's content invisible and ensure the size of the element to be fixed... i'll edit the post in a few seconds

Comment: **edited** -- this SHOULD work but can break your layout... if it does not what you want, we need a JSFiddle (or similar) snippet with an example that covers your sitation... imho, the other solutions are totally strange

Comment: Yeah that doesnt do anything, no longer even fades

Comment: yeah i NOW got your website-url... i'll chang

Comment: The tag is open after $(this).find('.Content_Frame_Image but it works perfectly. What a legend!! How did you learn all this because im really interested?

Comment: just keep learning as you do it and keep thinking 100% logically but open-minded to fail a solution and try a complete other one... you did always thought about hovering THE IMAGE, but you hover the CONTAINER on bottom of the page... if you enter it, the image should be disposed, when you leave it, the image should re-appear...
primarly simple, but I know what happens when you get stuck ;)

Comment: Thank you, i have noticed that there are some issues when hovering over one and moving to another one...i have updated the link...

Comment: yeah, because the event-queue will be interrupted but the LAST entry will not be completly finished...
just play around with the "stop()"-function in your code...

check out jquery-documentation for stop and use (for example) "stop(false, true)" or "stop(true, true)" or COMPLETELY remove stop...

Comment: you'll see what happenes... read the documentation of stop ;)

Comment: F.Y.O: I've found that .stop(false, true) works for what I need it for, once again thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use opacity instead of fadeOut, a callback function after your animation:

```
$(".Content_Frame_Image").hover(
function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow", function() {
        //move the element off-screen
        $(this).css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'left' : '-9999px'
        });
    });
},
function() {
    //move it back first
    $(this).css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'left' : '0'
    });
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could change it's z-index to be lower than the element it covers

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply...But I have just tried that and it causes the text to vanish, I have updated http://playing.everythingcreative.co.uk

Comment: If I change the z-index it does behind the text element