# Creating fluid layout and need JQuery to reset on size change

Tags: jquery, fade

Hi I am currently making a fadein/fadeout image over Div and I had some great help from 'TheHe' on this question [fadeOut/fadeIn image over element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148702/fadeout-fadein-image-over-element) but because I'm building it to work on multiple devices I need the script to only work when screen size is over 950px. This is most noticeable when moving from horizontal to vertical on an iPad so I want the script to reset itself when the screen is changed. if you visit http://playing.everythingcreative.co.uk you will get what I mean...Thank You

```
if( $(window).width() > 950)
    {

        $(".Content_Frame_Container")
        .each(function(){
            $(this).find('.Content_Frame_Image');
        })
        .hover( 
            function(){
                $(this).find('.Content_Frame_Image').stop(false, true).fadeOut('slow');
            }, 
            function(){
                $(this).find('.Content_Frame_Image').stop(false, true).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your complete solution was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $containers = $(".Content_Frame_Container");
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(this).width() > 950)
                return;
        $containers.each(function(){
            $(this).trigger('mouseleave');
        });
    });

    $containers
     .hover(function(){
             console.log('fadeout');
             $(this).find('.Content_Frame_Image').stop(false, true).fadeOut('slow');
         }, 
         function(){
            if($(window).width() <= 950)
                return;
             console.log('fadeout');
             $(this).find('.Content_Frame_Image').stop(false, true).fadeIn('slow');
         });         
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

encapsulate your code into the following:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
     // your code here
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Hello again! You should charge for your info...I actually tried that and got some bugs... I have updated the website with the code and it still causing elements to fadein

Comment: you can add me via skype --> send me an email (should be listed in my profile)